# jQuery Max Length Plugin

Tags: jquery-plugins

Is there any plugin for jQuery that would take an argument for the max length of a field and then size the width of the same field in respect to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculating the width depending on the field size is not possible, since different letters have different sizes (compare *i* and *w*). A possibility would be to take the size and multiply with the width of a *w*, but then the field would become very/too big. It also depends on font settings and I am unsure about possibilities to get font dimensions from JavaScript.

Taking this in mind: I do not think there are any (good) working plugins for jQuery out there... But maybe someone else is able to prove me wrong?

Comment: @Veger, ya that's what I was kinda thinkin, didn't know if someone knew of any decent solution tho. Some of these jQuery plugins out there are pretty slick, so I figured it was worth a shot.